# How do I get django-debug-toolbar to work with dajax?

Tags: ajax, django, django-debug-toolbar, dajax

It seems that `dajax` is hi-jacking the ajax requests from `django-debug-toolbar`

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway to work around this or a known solution?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem, going to dive into it myself.

Comment: Nope. Dug a little into the code but just couldn't justify investing the time to get it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, set `DAJAXICE_XMLHTTPREQUEST_JS_IMPORT = False` in your Django project settings.

By default, Dajaxice includes the [XmlHttpRequest.js](https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest) library:

- [dajaxice.core.js template](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/blob/master/dajaxice/templates/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js#L118)
- [__init__.py](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/blob/master/dajaxice/core/__init__.py#L10)

If you disable the inclusion of this third party javascript library, the Django Debug Toolbar can load panels properly. I have not noticed any issues with Dajaxice with the XmlHttpRequest.js library excluded- I believe it is only for compatibility with old IE browsers, though I'm not certain.