# Django-debug-toolbar panels stay at loading status

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm using django 1.8.2. I installed django-debug-toolbar the implicit way. The sidebar appears normally, but when I click to see a panel, it stay with the loading image without content.
Firebug reports no error, the `djdt-scroll` div is simply empty. When I examine the `/__debug__/render_panel/` request, I can see a normal output in the `html` tab in firebug.
In short terms,  django-debug-toolbar seems to work normally, but does not show the panel content. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using dajax or dajaxice? If so, try using the Django setting

```
DAJAXICE_XMLHTTPREQUEST_JS_IMPORT = False
```

See:
[How do I get django-debug-toolbar to work with dajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113494/how-do-i-get-django-debug-toolbar-to-work-with-dajax)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!